# ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic Property

Tags: mvvm-light

I am sure this is a MVVM Light newbie error but I need to ask. I am creating an WPF4 application using the MVVM Light framework and Ninject for DI. In the ViewModelLocator contructor I pass in the ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic value so I know to create DI with DesignTime data or RunTime data.
I thought that when you opened the MainWindow.xml in the designer ( VS2010 or Blend ) that the property would be True and the constructor would execute and break in debug if I had a breakpoint set. The application runs fine and debugs when ran correctly but I never get designtime data because the property is always false. Also does not seem that the constructor is executing when opened in designer.  I have watched Laurent's videos multiple times and I know this does work. Can someone please tell me what they think I must be doing wrong.

Orgbrat

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but try this when troubleshooting this kind of problem.

You'll need a simple Property to test: Create a "Foo" property (string) in the ViewModel and bind it to the XAML (use a TextBlock for example).

In the ViewModel

1. In the "Get", return an hard coded string (ex: "Step 1".  This will validate the "bindings" are valid.
2. Remove the "Get" hard code, and in the constructor, put a this.Foo = "Step 2" in the first line, this will validate that the constructor is called
3. Put a third set where the call is "callbacked", this will check that the GetData is being returned
4. in the "else" of the if (error != null), put the fourth set, and so on...

Example:  Here's my MainViewModel constructor.

```
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        this.Foo = "Step 2";

        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetData(
            (item, error) =>
            {
                this.Foo = "Step 3";

                if (error != null)
                {
                    // Report error here
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Foo = "Step 4";

                }


            });
    }
```

My last bug was that I had put the assignment of the data coming back from the GetData in the "if (error != null){...}" !  So it was never called.

Since then, I rewrite the constructor like this:

```
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {

        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetData(
            (item, error) =>
            {
                if (error == null)
                {
                    // Normal code here
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Report error here
                    return;
                }                    
            });
    }
```